# Ext.Net - Update Store Item With Combobox Text and Value

Tags: ext.net

Simple, I have a GridPanel and a FormPanel. Inside the form there is a combobox with a separate store. The GridPanel has another Store. The store items have a PersonName and PersonId properties. I would like to know how do I update those two properties with the combobox text to PersonName and value to PersonId respectively when I save the form changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
<ext:GridPanel runat="server" ID="gridTest" StoreID="storeData">
   <ColumnModel>
      <Columns>
         <ext:Column DataIndex="personId" Header="Person">
            <Editor>
               <ext:ComboBox runat="server" StoreID="storePeople" ValueField="personId" DisplayField="personName" />
            </Editor>
         </ext:Column>
      </Columns>
   </ColumnModel>

</ext:GridPanel>
```

This will allow you to select the name corresponding to an ID. The trick here is that in the grid though, it will show the ID number; not the name. To get it to show the name, you need to add a renderer onto the column to tell it to show a different value from the one it is bound to.